# Using Stack-Overflow as a Site's support platform

Tags: discussion, questions, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)
>   [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stack-overflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project)

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204178/how-will-i-get-to-use-the-darw2d-and-graphiti-for-drawing-flowcharts) question with the tag [draw2d](/questions/tagged/draw2d), I looked at the [draw2d site](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/support.html) and found this text:

> Support via eMail is massive transient and the result is not available to all users.
>   Please post your Question into Stackoverflow and send me the link to your Question.
>
> I didn’t provide support via email anymore.

I guess it is OK to say that technical questions will be answered in stackoverflow, but support consists of many things, not only technical answers. Is there any policy for these kinds of cases? Is it OK for a site/product/company to say that all support will be provided through stackoverflow?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81905/using-stack-overflow-for-topics-specific-to-a-product-in-a-cross-site-manner http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stackoverflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project among others

Comment: Saw many opinions but no answer. "Frowned upon" is not an answer. "Should not be done" is not an answer. The answer is either "yes, we accept the use of SO as the sole support platform of a product/project/company" or "no, we don't accept this and will do all that we can to stop this".