# Can I create a new section on Stack Overflow dedicated to a new Topic?

Tags: feature-request

Can I create a new section / community on Stack Overflow which will be dedicated to one particular topic. I am a Java developer working on a framework called ATG. This is a globally used framework and I realised that there are very few blogs dedicated to it.

So I am thinking of creating one section on Stack Overflow (if I can), which will address this need specifically. Please advise.

Comment: similar to [use stackoverflow as the official support site of an open-source project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stackoverflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project)

Comment: and [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Comment: For some reason, I think the whole [facebook] thing came about because of a massive buttload of cash transferred hands.

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow doesn't have "sections" in the way that you seem to be envisaging.  All it has is *tags*.  Every question has a number of tags, and you can look at only the questions that have the tags you're interested in.

In this case, just use the [atg](/questions/tagged/atg) tag, which already exists, and has 21 questions: browse the ones that exist – adding answers if you can help – and ask new ones if you need help.

Comment: It actually does have "sections" if you think about the mini-sites like facebook.stackoverflow.com. That's the only one at this point in time, though.

Comment: Well, not unless you have lots of money and want to flood SO with people asking off-topic questions about facebook apps.

Comment: Is facebook.stackoverflow.com really all that different from browsing the appropriate tags on StackOverflow? Not to my mind...

Comment: Not really, but it does provide an automatic grouping for related tags in the form of a subdomain. It's very much like having a good set of favorite and ignored tags, but those tags are maintained by the Stack Overflow team rather than an individual.

Comment: Don't forget to claim the tag wiki!

Comment: Meh, never even *heard* of the facebook. domain until now. It's actually worse in my opinion since there's no indicator other than the logo or domain. that you've stumbled onto a section focused on facebook. Compare that to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django where at least django is written out.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific purpose, it's probably appropriate to just use the tag, as noted in lonesomeday's answer.

If you're doing something distinct enough that it deserves its own stackexchange site though, you can propose it on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks donroby. That answers my question.