# Do questions on SO need to be of interest to the majority of users?

Tags: discussion

I [asked about asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133848/digiflow-questions) about a software that I use that has some coding involved but would not be of interest to the majority of users of SO. I found it difficult to get a clear answer about whether this was ok or not.

I would be interested knowing whether questions need to be of interest to the *majority of users* of SO.

The SO [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) do not mention that questions need to be of interest to the majority of users but the impression I got from more reputable SO users was that this is expected.

(There were some other problems, like my phrasing of questions and explicit stating of affiliations but I'd like to leave that aside for the moment as I think I have mostly got that fixed).

Comment: A *majority?* No. Hardly any question fulfills that requirement, seeing as how many tags there are. But *some* users, yeah. More than a handful

Comment: Re "how much is a handful": a home-made language so obscure that it is known only to the author and maybe a couple of their friends would probably be too localized. But your specific example, DigiFlow, looks like it's definitely on-topic (as long as it's about programming it). It's a product in open circulation; that it is a very specific niche product doesn't really matter. Give it a try, and if it gets closevoted let us know, I'm sure you'll find sympathetic ears here

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags I was *this close* (holds forefinger and thumb 1cm apart) to flagging you as spam, then I clicked your username and decided not to. For now.

Comment: @Widor want a handbag? Is cheap. High quality. Worldwide shipping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No question will ever be of interest to a **majority** of Stack Overflow users; however, questions *are* expected to potentially be of use to (some) *future visitors*.  The too localized close reason explains this:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable,

Answer (score 2):

> I would be interested knowing whether questions need to be of interest
>   to the majority of users of SO.

To answer that specifically, the answer is a straight "no". In fact, I'd wager that very few questions on StackOverflow are of interest to the *majority* of users (i.e. > 50%).

That said, if it's only of interest to a few, or for a short time period it would be closed as "**Too Localized**", as per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close):

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.