# Encouraging usage of SO within a large company - potential problems

Tags: support, sock-puppets

A reference question: [Using SO as a interoffice tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117871/168681)

I'm exactly in the situation as the author of the question cited above. I work for a large sw company and I've been thinking of encouraging fellow developers to ask their technical questions on SO, provided that they meet the not-too-localized criteria. We'd share links to questions in our internal forums.

We all, though, hundreds of developers, connect to the world through the same proxy. Won't it eliminate us quickly, as perceived spammers/sock puppets? Does SO handle well posts from large organizations?

Comment: The question you link to pretty much answers your question: It's important that all the various developers take some care to try to avoid voting for each other's posts. An occasional vote would not be a big deal, but if a pattern forms...

Comment: Not quite, the original question concerns abusive voting patterns, I'm specifically asking about problems resulting from many posts from the same IP.

Comment: Look at the answer more than the question; The question does ask about some things you aren't here, but the answer and its comments are spot-on for what you need to know.