# Where should I have my questions posted?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Last year I started an open source project. I have like over 90% of spammers per day in my forum.

I'm considering having my questions answered on one of the Stack Exchange sites.

Which Stack Exchange site should I use if this is allowed?

Just for the record:

1. The software is WarrantyTrack and is open source (available on [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge))
2. I have an average of 100 queries per day - mostly spammers/bots.

Comment: I would suggest you rather find a better spam fighting/management solution for your forum.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for the thought but I honestly can't do anything better. I'm using phpbb and it's got all the magic in place. Fortunately (and unfortunately) I have even enabled confirmation for creating accounts and I have around 100 new accounts to verify. This is awful. Anyway, thanks for your inputs :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general we do not recommend that you use Stack Overflow as support for your projects.

See Jeff's answer to [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/1288)

Also see the answers on: [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19852/1288)