# Is Stack Overflow the official PayPal support site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

In the [Community/ PayPal forums](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support) section at [PayPal's developers site](https://developer.paypal.com/) we can read this:

> **Ask our community**
>
> Visit StackOverflow to check out our [PayPal forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal).

Is there any sort of agreement between Stack Overflow and PayPal or are the latter just being extremely cheeky?

Comment: I don't like that it uses the word "our", as if they did all the work of creating StackOverflow just to add the PayPal tag.

Comment: ***STACK OVERFLOW IS NOT A FORUM*** but anyway, I think this should be reworded. "Our" is not a good word. "Forum" is not a good word.

Comment: [Jeff Atwood seemed to think](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19869/147315), at one point anyways, that this isn't a good idea.

Comment: A fresh discussion about this has opened recently [here, on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296339/419956).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no official agreement or arrangement that I know of, but it is not uncommon for companies to encourage their users and employees to use Stack Overflow for *development* support.

We encourage that, so long as nobody tries to outsource their entire support system (including discussions, bug reports, feature requests, etc) to us. After all, nothing beats an expert answer from someone employed by the very company whose stuff you're using.

Comment: The [tag:paypal] tag appears to be sponsored so they do pay, isn't it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sure. But tag sponsorship isn't really related to or a prerequisite for directing dev support to Stack Overflow.

Comment: My problem with this, as someone familiar with PayPal development, is that there aren't a lot of questions that can be easily asked that meet the strict format required by the site FAQ. A lot of questions that I had for instance were fairly broad. It doesn't help that there isn't clear documentation for specific versions of the various PayPal APIs.