# What tags should we use for 2 open source projects with the same name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, new-users

I am part of the dev team of [Silex](http://projects.silexlabs.org/?/silex.v2/), an open source website builder. We think of getting rid of the old forums of Silex and we would like to send the users to Stack Overflow instead.

But the problem is that the tag [silex](/questions/tagged/silex) is already in use by silex, the php micro framework (much younger project, for developers).

Is there a standard way to handle that on Stack Overflow? Maybe ask the other Silex to share a tag?! I don't think so..

Maybe we should use [silex.io](/questions/tagged/silex.io) or [silex.me](/questions/tagged/silex.me) (it will be the new domain name in a few weeks)

Or else a tag like [silex-live-web-creation](/questions/tagged/silex-live-web-creation), or [silex-web](/questions/tagged/silex-web)?

Comment: I'd vote against the domain name, that's for sure.

Comment: Isn't the mistake picking the same name as another open source project in the first place?

Comment: @Eric It sure is, but the OP's project happens to be the older one of the two.

Comment: Not going to be a participant in the tag (nor in the other silex tag), but I'd suggest [tag:silex-web] and also consider renaming the existing [tag:silex] to [tag:silex-framework] to help avoid confusion

Comment: `We think of getting rid of the old forums of Silex and we would like to send the users to Stack Overflow instead.` I remember that SO is OK with sending users over, but SO should be one option of support, not the only channel.

Comment: @nhahtdh Remember how facebook.SO worked out!

Comment: Make sure the users you send to SO know it is not a forum.

Comment: Hey, thx for the answers!

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes, we could have Silex-web and Silex-framework, but I doubt that the other Silex community would accept this, because they use this tag for a long time now, and also they already knew that there was another Silex for designers before taking the name Silex... I guess they do not like our initiative very much. Note that both projects are French, and I personally emailed the project lead but he never answers :-/

Comment: @Wooble ok, I think that I understand... you mean that it is more a community? Or something like Wikipedia, a knowledge base?

Comment: Well, it's a question and answer site. If your users have concrete programming questions, SO is great. If they want to have extended discussions about the framework, it's not (and they're likely to leave frustrated after having questions closed and downvoted).

Comment: @lexa in some respects the tag's community has input, but in other respects they need to play nice with the entire SO community.  If there are 2 silex projects that are very different, you don't want to confuse your users, so it makes sense to make sure the tags are easily distinguishable.  That's my personal opinion though, other may choose to disagree.

Comment: Or maybe we could have the Silex tag on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: @lexa if your questions will be on topic for that site, sure.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Silex users are designers... and web design is design I guess.

Comment: @lexa: if you and your users do not already make use of StackExchange and understand how it works, please do not get rid of your existing solution to move here. Everybody is going to have a bad time.

Comment: Just an idea: why not having a "silex.stackexchange.com" dedicated to the project community? If all the Q&A goes from the forum to SO it could be worth having your own.

Comment: @NorTicUs he is free to propose it, but he needs a community to support it and get the proposal through the [area51.SE] process.  That could take years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here and the comments are somewhat spread out, so let's deal with the issues one-by-one.

**Tag Name** -  Tags should be descriptive, easy to remember, and not invite confusion.

This is a rather unique situation I think as you normally would only have the same project name for 2 different projects/libraries/languages if the 2 projects branched from each other at some time and usually one or both pick a new name at some point.

Typically when there is some naming confusion, appending a "-x" (where x is another descriptive name) to the end is appropriate.  However, when this is done, it is usually best to rename *BOTH* projects' tags to avoid confusing users (mistagging can result in someone not seeing the appropriate questions or following the wrong tag).

- [silex](/questions/tagged/silex) - Since there is another (newer) project with the same name, both of you using the same tag would be very confusing to everyone so that is out.
- [silex.me](/questions/tagged/silex.me) - Make some sense if that is going to be your domain, but if you are a new user unfamiliar with your domain, and you see a tag "silex" and "silex.me", you might pick silex since that is your project's actual name.  Again, more confusion.
- [silex-live-web-creation](/questions/tagged/silex-live-web-creation) - If a brand new users will know this is your project, then go for it.  Personally, I think long tag names just take up too much screen real estate, especially on mobile devices.
- [silex-web](/questions/tagged/silex-web) - Again, if a brand new users will know this is your project, then go for it.  This is shorter and more mobile friendly.  This would get my vote, but then again, I've used the word "silex" 10 more times in this answer then I've every done in my entire life, so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

Regardless of which name you pick, you still have the problems of confusion with the existing tag.  To that end, I would suggest proposing a name change for that tag to something equally descriptive but less confusing for new users, like [silex-framework](/questions/tagged/silex-framework) or [silex-php](/questions/tagged/silex-php).  Since they had the [silex](/questions/tagged/silex) tag first, it would likely have to be a synonym of the newer tag, but it would force users to see something descriptive enough that confusion and mistags would be reduced.

**Replacing your forums with SO** - you did not ask for help on this, but you are going to get some unsolicited advice since in one of your comments you seemed confused by [Wooble's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135736/wooble) comment.  His follow up comment might have cleaned the confusion, but in case it didn't, you need to reconsider this idea or at least make sure you know what you are in for.  From your comments here and your [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197229/silex-live-web-creation-on-stackoverflow), I'm not sure you fully grasp what SE sites are about, and how aggressively we moderate questions to ensure they are on-topic and of good quality.

While other 3rd parties have tried to encourage their communities to use Stack Overflow, it is not appropriate to completely replace your existing support community with Stack Overflow.  There are a number of posts scattered around, but here is a collection:

- [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)
- [Is Stack Overflow the official PayPal support site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173138/is-stack-overflow-the-official-paypal-support-site?lq=1)
- [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stack-overflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project)
- [Using Stack Overflow for topics specific to a product (in a cross-site manner)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81905/using-stack-overflow-for-topics-specific-to-a-product-in-a-cross-site-manner)

You can encourage your users to ask questions, but there need to be valid, on topic posts.  Additionally, general support and bug reports have no home here, so you need to maintain another avenue for users to be able to contact the dev team directly and to be able to post and report bugs.

[Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29) did it the proper way, but leaving all of their support forums up and just recommending questions be asked on SO.

[**Moving to another SE site-**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197204/what-tags-should-we-use-for-2-open-source-projects-with-the-same-name#comment624246_197204)

> Or maybe we could have the Silex tag on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com ?? – lexa 22 mins ago

That's completely up to you but you still have to be on-topic.  You can't just create a tag, say "go ask questions here", and expect the SE community to accept those questions.  Questions that are off-topic or don't otherwise fit withing the asking guidelines of that site are going to be downvoted, closed, and you are going to have some upset users.

[Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/182513) to one of the questions I linked above is spot on.  You can't just magically create a community on Stack Overflow or another SE site.  And you can't just create a tag.  The questions need to exist first and you can create a tag to add to those questions.  If you create a tag without questions, then the tag is just going to get deleted by the automatic cleanup that runs every 24 hours.

It is best to cultivate the site organically on an appropriate SE site, running it in parallel with your support forums and encouraging your users to ask on-topic questions on SE.  Then as the SE community grows, you can reduce your support forums.

Comment: +1, facebook.so was such a fantastic failure that it is quite obvious that if your users are not already using SO and immersed in the culture, *dropping what you have now for SO is not going to work*.