# SO policy on directing questions to specific entities

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, policy

Specificly, this [question - **Can we get an OFFICIAL Instagram Response**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909878/can-we-get-an-official-instagram-response-to-error-400-when-liking-photos) was just asked

Due to this [policy](http://instagram.com/developer/support/) by instagram which states

> **We are actively monitoring Stack Overflow** and we will be removing the
>   Google Group soon. If you have questions that have not been answered,
>   **please post to Stack Overflow or report bugs with the Bug Tool**.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Rosinante What is the official policy, and more interestingly, this would have been a perfectly acceptable question had it not been directed toward a specific person.  I could actually see go coming from this sort of this with perhaps an instagram support tag or something.

Comment: Related: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966), [Product support redirects to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195558), [Is Stack Overflow the official PayPal support site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173138)

Comment: I think it would have been marginal even without the 'invoke the name and get an official response,' but there's only one of me.

Comment: `this would have been a perfectly acceptable question had it not been directed toward a specific person` maybe, but it *was* directed towards a specific person and that's not on topic on Stack Overflow. Just because Instagram tells you we are their new tech support forum doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: «I could actually see go[od] coming from this sort of this with perhaps an instagram support tag or something.» [Been there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership?lq=1).

Answer (score 6):

Questions posted on Stack Overflow need to comply with Stack Overflow's guidelines, and there is no exception for Instagram related questions.

Posting a question asking for an official response from Instagram is most definitely off topic on SO.

If you want to complain about this, you want to talk to Instagram for creating a misleading policy. They should have added a paragraph telling askers to make sure their questions work under [Stack Overflow's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maybe if the OP took a selfie of themselves holding a sign asking for help, and then filtered it a bit, and then posted it ...

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is not meant to be a place where questions are directed to specific entities, no matter whether those entities *wish* to have questions directed at them or not. Questions should be 'directed' at the community at large, and should not be so specific or require deep, insider knowledge.

I don't think the question in... question truly needs *only* an official response. Or, at least I think it'd be worth a community response. If it gets an 'official' one - great. Otherwise, I think it could also stand to be worded differently.

---

Disclaimer: I read the question very briefly, and it does seem possible it's not specifically a question about coding, but... ehh..

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really seeing how this is even related to programming. Sounds more like an Instagram bug report.

Comment: I've taken a stab at editing it to make it less a support request and more a "WTF? Docs are wrong." It still may not fly, though.

Answer (score 1):

Some users of stackoverflow with close vote privileges feel that the question in question is not a programming question, since it is about policy / TOS of Instagram. <del>instagram</del> Facebook can paint themselves blue and run around their parking lot all they like, but that doesn't change the views of the community here.