# Is it OK to put a small FAQ on a relevant Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

If someone has build software or a library or something else, is it OK to add a small quantity of questions with answers on one of the relevant Stack Exchange sites in order to create a small FAQ and to bootstrap the community around it?

Comment: I'd say no.  Wherever you're distributing your product can contain your FAQs.  Loosely related [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stack-overflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project).

Comment: Related (cross site): *[Is it okay to direct support requests to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368763)*

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is focused on content, not who posts it.

If you post valid questions with valid answers then by all means, I'd say go ahead and do it. This will help other people, and doesn't really matter who posts it.

**Things to keep in mind to play it safe and fair though**:

- Post full and detailed answers, without links to your product, as that would be considered spam.
- Do not use separate accounts for asking and answering, that would be considered bad sock puppet.
- Do not add signature to all the posts (e.g. "I'm the author of the software), that would be considered noise, and should be only in your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

Not really - Practically, SE is not a replacement for your own documentation - sticking that sort of thing on an external site makes it a lot harder to find.

On bigger sites, its too busy to get any real traction (too much post churn) to build up a community and get attention for a library or application - and it feels dangerously close to an attempt at astroturfing or self promotion.

*Some* projects do use our sites as an *additional* not primary means of support. To an extent - well written, *individual* questions about your library might be useful for folks, though, people might be annoyed if all your questions were self answers.

On the other hand, it might be nice to seed one or two questions, get a *well written* tag wiki up, and help out folks with questions about your library - especially where its the sort of "I'm trying to do a thing - but foo?" question with an answer in the form of "here's how you do it - you need to do bar - this is why foo happened"

So in this situation, SE would act as a good *supplement* to your own documentation and community, but isn't really a good tool for bootstrapping

Comment: Thanks for answer, I agree that it should be only a complement to a good documentation.