# Can I have a link to the "ask as question" page with the tag field pre-filled?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

We'd like to encourage people to ask questions on Stack Overflow. For this, we'd like to have on our site a link to the Stack Overflow [ask as question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but we'd like to have the "tag" field pre-filled with a tag that would then help us find the questions. Is this possible?

Use case:

- I work on an open source web forms product (Orbeon Forms), which implements the W3C XForms technology.
- On the web site for Orbeon Forms, we'd like to encourage people to ask XForms questions on Stack Overflow.
- As suggested by others here, this could be done by having somewhere on our site some HTML as follows: `Have questions about XForms? <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tagnames=xforms">Ask them on Stack Overflow</a>`.

Comment: This will not go down well if you speak with a certain cowboy.

Comment: What tag are you even looking to pre-fill? Hopefully it's a language and not a person/community.

Comment: Who is "we", what is the site and what fields are you thinking of? What would the interface look like on your site?

Comment: All, I just added more information under "Use case" in the question, which hopefully clarifies the use case I have in mind.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done with the tags parameter:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=java+xml

There's also a similar [`title` parameter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/67699/3), but its utility is limited since titles must be unique.

Answer (score 6):

I think we need a lot more details on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.

Stack Overflow isn't intended as an outsourced support forum.

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/using-stackoverflow-as-a-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Comment: @codinghorror, thank you for taking the time to respond. I added the use case I have in mind as part of the question. You'll let me know if you'd like to encourage people to use Stack Overflow this way or not.