# Linking to "ask a question" form

Tags: support

I am maintaining a [PHP UI framework](http://agiletoolkit.org/). When downloaded it comes with a couple of default pages. One of those pages is dedicated to explain to users how they can ask questions about the framework.

1. Is that's OK to developers to stackoverflow for asking questions here?
2. I would like to have a link which will automatically fill in keyword suggestion. Is there a way to embed keyword into this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Do any questions about this framework already exist on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not yet, it's been published only recently. World is yet to discover it.

Comment: OH actually there are couple! yay

Comment: See the answers to [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282) for your first question.

Comment: And see [Can I have a link to the “ask as question” page with the tag field pre-filled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33195/can-i-have-a-link-to-the-ask-as-question-page-with-the-tag-field-pre-filled) for your second question. Combined with the link @Bill posted above, I think this proves that direct linking to the Ask page is not such a good idea. Linking to Search or [specific tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-toolkit) would be better, if you'd ask me.

Comment: I suppose it is fine then as long as those are questions.

Comment: (I don't know what you mean, @romaninsh.)

Comment: From those links I understand that for an open-source projects it's permitted to suggest to ask questions here, as long as they are not support or feature requests and can be valuable for others. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm simply trying to make it easier for others to find answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just append `?tags=php` (for example) to the URL to prepopulate the tags field.

Appending `&title=title%20goes%20here` will prepopulate the title tag as well.

[Here's an example link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=php)

Comment: Awesome. That answers one of my questions.

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't users first search if their question has already been asked, @romaninsh and Bill?

Comment: @Arjan shouldn't that be handled by the search done when they type the question title? That seems to be the current amount of effort people put into searching for questions on Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: @Arjan: That would be my preference.  They will still get a list of suggestions when they type in a title, so that will get used as much as it ever does.

Comment: True, sad as it is, @Mark. But though technically supported: does this mean we really want hotlinking to the Ask page? Unregistered users will go through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first when following such direct link, but even then I'd like them to at least browse through some questions first. Just to get a feeling of the site...

Comment: I'm certainly integrate the stackapps API for searches and will have bundled search UI sometime in the future, but for now I think providing link is just enough.

Comment: I would like everyone to post a link to an example reproducing their question. Is there any way I can encourage this by specifying a `body` or `content` as part of the URL? I tried `body`, `content`, `contents`, and `question`...

Answer (score 4):

Be very careful that you have followed the guideline here:

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282)