# How can I programmatically set a tag and propose a question title on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, api, stack-overflow

I would like to provide a customized link from my Web site "Ask a question on stackoverflow" so that visitors can easily post a question related to the individual topic. Currently, I just link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, but this means that I cannot suggest a title or tag for the question, which would be helpful for directing this question to qualified people.

Is there any way to pass a title text and / or tag suggestion to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ?

Comment: and also : http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking to "ask a question" form..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86491/linking-to-ask-a-question-form)

Answer (score 3):

[/questions/ask?title=This is the title&tags=tag-a tag-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=This%20is%20the%20title%20text&tags=tag-a%20Tag-b)

Comment: Correct, but Martin, be sure to read [Jeff's statement about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86491/linking-to-ask-a-question-form/86829#86829).