# Ask a pre-tagged question from a tag page

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, tags-page

I really like using Stack Overflow for problem solving in communities around open source libraries. One problem that I've found is that it seems to be difficult to guide users both to existing questions that may solve their problem *and* into asking properly tagged questions. While we can [link "ask" with a pre-filled tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67699/142718) directly, there's no explicit call to action when viewing a tag's page.

I'd love to see a "Ask A [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) Question" button displayed somewhere prominently when viewing [foo](/questions/tagged/foo). This means we could link to the tag page to encourage users to search for existing answers, but also provide an easy means of asking a question from this jump-off point. Is this something that can be added?

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical such  a feature would be of much benefit. I think it would be prudent to do some some testing before implementing this feature. It seems to me that very few of the poorly-tagged questions that come in would be from users who were previously on the tag page for the tag they should have used.

I think people who visit a tag page are much more likely to be looking for questions to answer, than to ask a question themselves, and those looking to answer questions in a tag already know how to use that tag.

If users are commonly asking questions from a tag page, it's entirely possible they are asking other questions that should not be tagged. Then when they go to tag their question, they might leave the default tag, possibly resulting in more incorrectly-tagged questions.

Just my 2¢, Stack Exchange developers could probably give more insight into this situation.