# When clicking "Ask Question" from within a tag page, automatically add this tag to the new question

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

Suppose I want to ask where I can ask a question on Stack Exchange. Ideally, I'd first browse existing [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions, and if I can't find what I want, will ask a new question.

Assuming I do it from the tag page itself:

[image: Ask question from tag page]

I would like it to auto add this tag to the question's tag list. I believe this is the expected behavior for most users, and worst case the user can remove the tag.

This request is very similar to [Ask a pre-tagged question from a tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222353/ask-a-pre-tagged-question-from-a-tag-page), however differs enough: the other request asks for a new, separate button, I suggest to have the existing button automatically add the tag.

Comment: I prefer another button personally. I'm not necessarily asking a [tag:site-recommendation] question if I'm viewing that tag; I might simply be just viewing that tag. And automatically adding a tag when it's not the expected behaviour (it doesn't match what the button does elsewhere for example) or even obvious that is what is going to happen isn't great.

Comment: Sha, if it mandatorily adds the [tag:site-recommendation] tag does it also [add the **obligatory** support or discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag too - as site-rec questions seem to be split between the two tags.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot good and fair point, please post this as answer if you can.

Comment: @Rob no, that's not in the scope of my feature request. I ask only to add the tag viewed by the user, without further complications.

Comment: Sha, it's not a complication it's mandatory; you can't submit the question without doing so. --- You start the premise of your question thinking that new users use the tags to search (too bad they don't actually find their answer instead), then you say: `"I believe this is the expected behavior for most users."` - it's unlikely, seldom do we need to edit to add this tag. --- Where's the data that supports this belief, and denies the need for the mandatory tag too. --- Rather than "expected" it all seems unexpected, only one similar prior request (with the duplicate having very few upvotes) ...

Comment: @Rob your idea has a point, but still, that's not what I had in mind. You can also post this as answer, and who knows.... maybe SE will decide to adopt it instead of my own idea.

Comment: My comment is intended as [constructive feedback or request for clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/282094), and not as a [partial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301808/282094). See those links for why we are supposed to comment, and when not; what is expected to improve the question.

Comment: @Rob I don't see it this way. I did not ask to add other tags, and disagree that it's essential part of the request. If you think so then you oppose my request which is fine. But there is nothing to clarify, and your feedback is legit, never said otherwise. :)

Comment: Too bad tag excerpt doesn't support markdown/HTML. Otherwise, we can just put `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=support,site-recommendation` on there.