# To what extent can I encourage users to visit SO?

Tags: discussion, advertising, referrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should software vendors discourage StackOverflow questions from their developer community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68753/should-software-vendors-discourage-stackoverflow-questions-from-their-developer)

If we have a piece of software development software, to what extent are we allowed to encourage users of our software to post questions on SO?

Comment: What kind of questions? You mean about the software?

Comment: Note: [Qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org) has SO as [additional channel to ask questions about it](http://qooxdoo.org/community).

Comment: @Pekka, questions about how to do something in the software, basically legitimate SO questions.  I'm just wondering what the ethics are on encouraging users to use SO when we have commercial interest.

Comment: If your software isn't a programming tool then SO is not the place for questions on how to use it, SU *might* be a better fit.