# Getting tags created for use with a JavaScript library

Tags: feature-request, support

While I can do it the hard way in acquiring privileges to be able to create my own tags (I've just started contributing to Stack Overflow so have a ways to go yet), I'd like to offer users of our php.js JavaScript library (at http://phpjs.org ) the ability to ask and answer questions on php.js using its specific tag.

I think it already merits having its own tag, given that

1. If you search Google for PHP functions, you'll often find php.js showing up in results
2. We already have 128 users on Ohloh, were featured on Digg, etc.
3. Some people have already asked questions on Stack related to php.js (e.g., [str_shuffle() equivalent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079385/str-shuffle-equivalent-in-javascript) ).

Could someone create such php.js tags for us on Stack Overflow, so we can start developing an API for our site to let our users plug into Stack to better ensure their questions get answered, as well as ensure those offering answers can get rewarded?

I think "php.js" (and "phpjs" as a synonym) should be suitable if someone wouldn't mind doing this for us and our users, assuming it is appropriate for me to ask this.

Comment: `If you search Google for PHP functions, you'll often find php.js showing up in results.` Sounds frustrating.

Comment: So, is it frustrating to you that PHP results show up when you search for C functions? Sorry, but reusing existing names to leverage existing knowledge is a (convenient) feature of programming languages (and language in general). Besides, it is often the slightly tangential results which introduces a person to new ideas. If you want an exact search, add "php" and hopefully Google will weight it accordingly (or use "-phpjs").

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful that you're not running afoul of the guidance at

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282)

In particular, you should list several places on the public internet to seek out support, NOT just us. If you list us as your sole "support", that's grounds for banning.