# Policy for use of Stack Overflow as an open source support Site

Tags: discussion, community, policy, outsourcing

Suppose there is a completely open technology that applies to many platforms and languages alike and in parallel.

Suppose the promoting the use of such technology is done with addressing specific problems with specific answers and solutions.

I have personally affiliated/disclaimed my answers properly (and earned accepted answer by doing it), because the technology does apply as-is to T4 code generation and DSL issues.

We have set up forums for discussions of this technology, but I would see it could help for much wider audience in general.

What is Stack Exchange's policy on encouraging people to come here to ask their specific questions? To fill in the community database, as the technology is completely open, completely open-source.

I mean if we encouraged people to come over here to ask their questions instead of trying to maintain our own forum for questions and answers.

For the open-source and other community aspect, it sounds exactly what Stack Overflow is all about, but I would like to understand how do people get here and how Stack Exchange wants the questions to find their way here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282)

> I think this idea of using Stack Overflow as an official support forum is inside-out : the *community* has to adopt the project, find it of interest, and talk about it on Stack Overflow.
>
> Pushing to one particular destination from inside the project feels like forcing a fit for the community rather than letting one organically evolve.
>
> One way is as you saw with Subsonic -- where **they simply provide a single link to Stack Overflow among *other* links of places people can go to discuss Subsonic**. I think that's an OK nudge and if you want to seed it with questions yourself, that's fine too.
>
> But outsourcing your forums or support to Stack Overflow alone is abusive and definitely frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. As this is not a product anyone is selling, but a completely open, standards based methodology to use existing technologies, I think it fits particularly well on Stackoverflow. We will still host our own forums as well, but ideally this method applies to wide range of technologies, platforms and everything related to software development.

Comment: @kallex that doesn't mean the community wants to talk about it. The push to talk must come from the community, not the project organizers.

Comment: I understand. I was first thinking of putting the link to SO, but now I don't think that's appropriate. After thinking about it, the methodology questions should enter here at natural pace.