# Can I use a SO tag in lieu of hosting a developer forum for my licensees?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

My company has been developing a game engine for a few years and using it for our projects.  We are looking into licenscing it to other developers.  Can I create a tag on StackOverflow and tell our licencees to use it instead of hosting a forum for them to use?  Or is that sort of thing frowned upon?

Comment: possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project