# Is SO an offical help site for Aptana?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

On the [Aptana Support Page](http://aptana.com/support) the [Browse Discussions](http://www.aptana.com/r/aphelp) link redirects to SO.  I was wondering if this was officially sanctioned?

If it is, then it seems a little unfair that questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756603/error-install-new-software) are voted down and have close votes cast against them.  This question does seem to be just about on topic for SO, being that it is regarding a development tool.

If not, then I will cast close votes against these questions when I see them.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project

Comment: @scrooge - A quote from Jeff's answer `outsourcing your forums or support to Stack Overflow alone is abusive and definitely frowned upon.` is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: The link and blurb don't actually encourage people to do anything other than read these topics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StackOverflow is a community site - as far as the users of the site are concerned it is not the "official" support site for anything, Aptana included.

That Aptana have chosen to redirect developers to StackOverflow is their decision - the level of support their users will get will be governed by the will of the SO community as a whole and not in their control.

The question that you linked to is off-topic to StackOverflow - the people behind Aptana should have a support option outside of StackOverflow for this kind of question.

Comment: I thought the FAQ point `software tools commonly used by programmers` would cover this? If I've misunderstood then I'll happily vote to close.

Comment: @shanethehat - This is a very specific question about a plugin. The close votes are more to do with the quality of the question than anything.

Comment: Fair enough, I think I see the difference.

Comment: @shanethehat - That's the problem with delegating support to SO. Valid support questions by your users are not in your control.

Comment: It's [Synergy](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2314/synergy-specific-entry-page) all over again.

Comment: @Scrooge - didn't know about that. Does look pretty close.

Comment: @Oded - It's not quite true that SO isn't an "offical" support site for anything as under the guise of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com it is "the new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers" as per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid - It is not the support site for FB _users_. And in that guise there is FB branding...

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid - The support page on FB also makes it very clear that SO is not specific to FB.

Comment: True indeed, I was just pointing out a slight error in your statement ;)