# Registering a new tag / using SO-infrastructure for own project's Q/A

Tags: discussion

I will release my framework to the open source world on github and expect new users to have questions about it. I've never been a big fan of mailing lists, however, a big fan of SO.

Does SO want me to use their infrastructure for Q/A about my framework? I'd need a tag on SO, so I could register for all questions about the framework. I would also write a lot of self-answered questions in order to create a FAQ for my users without having my own infrastructure.

My advantages: no maintaining of my own forum software / bugfixes / security / whatsoever.
SO advantage: if the framework hits off -> lots of clicks here

Is it "ok" with the administration if I start to write self-answered Q/A about my framework here and ask for a tag as soon as I have like 10 to 15 articles ready or is this non-favored behavior?

Comment: As an additional note for other users stumbling about my "clone" instead of the original, here another interesting thread with Joel himself answering: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133522/encyclopedia-stack-exchange-vs-commercial-products