# Any chance to create a new stackoverflow Tag for commercial product?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, company

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

The idea is the following:

The company will encourage its customers to ask questions about its software products on stackoverflow. When user clicks 'Ask a Question' on a corporate website the user is redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask with a 'Tags' filled in.

1. Is it allowed to do this on stackoverflow?
2. Are there any chance to create a custom tag (except having 1500 reputation)? The company will use this tag to find questions asked bout its products.

Comment: somthing like this [anydac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anydac) ?

Comment: Well, you could sponsor a non-existent tag. They may create it for you.