# Can I use Stack Overflow as a product support community?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Before I start this may be a [possible duplicate of this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

I was thinking about open-sourcing a framework I've built up over the years. Probably on github or google code but I really dislike the github communication flow also google code communication is all pretty mailing-list based which I'm never a fan of, I'd probably occasionally check the messages on GH or GC but I'd be much more responsive if I could support it here and encourage people this direction.

I know that this seems a bit like outsourcing a forum but personally I'd imagine that half of the potential users of the framework would already be here and would also find it better than to have to go signup somewhere else or open another mail folder to filter a deluge of mailnglist thoughput.

Is this in SO's interest or should this be a github thing?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That one is about using SO as a support forum, which is at least still in the Q&A arena. This seems to be about replacing a news/status-update mailing list, which is a substantially different format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always have the liberty to direct people to SO for support with your framework. Just be careful in mentioning the relationship with the site—Stack Overflow is not the official provider of product support from your framework, it's simply a very useful resource for such things. You are not directly affiliated with the website, obviously, so I'd be sure to make that clear.

The nature of this is that you're just suggesting Stack Overflow as a resource for help, so it should be okay (and I'd imagine it's encouraged, since it brings traffic).

Though, I would also keep other methods for user support open in case they don't have an account or don't know much about Stack Overflow.