# Can someone please add the tag [tickzoom]?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-creation

Can someone add the tag tickzoom at stackoverflow?
I don't have enough reputation yet to add the tag.

Why? We developers at tickzoom want to track the specific tag tickzoom so we can watch for questions and answer them timely.

What is tickzoom? TickZoom (tickzoom.com) is a software framework for traders to build their own automated trading systems. We want to encourage users to post questions about setup and configuration at serverfault and about programming issues at stackoverflow. In fact, since you encourage to ask and answer, we'll do that for common support questions.

If you have the ability to add it at serverfault also, please do. I requested the same in meta serverfault as well.

Comment: If nobody asks questions about it - it would not make sense to create it. Empty tags get removed automatically after 24 hours.

Comment: Related: [Can I use SO as a product support community?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144552)

Comment: Related: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966)

Comment: @juergen: Good point. Thanks. I will ask & answer a common issue with installing tickzoom today so the tag will be around.

Comment: @Pekka. Yes. My understanding is that it is encouraged to do so. The downside is that you don't "own" or control the content but we feel that the advantages outweigh the downsides.

Comment: @Wayne the central thing to bear in mind from the second link: `the community has to adopt the project, find it of interest, and talk about it on Stack Overflow. Pushing to one particular destination from inside the project feels like forcing a fit for the community rather than letting one organically evolve.` but if legit questions come up naturally, everything's cool

Comment: @Pekka Oh. Thanks, I'm glad that you pointed this out. We will setup a separate forum for the tickzoom user community to use for chit chat about tickzoom. But we want to have tickzoom developers (like myself) only answer technical questions on stackoverflow. Is that cool?

Comment: @Wayne that sounds fine.

Comment: @Pekka By the way, our new website will also refer people to a list of 3rd party consultants that offer fee for service support for tickzoom. So between that option, the community forum, stackoverflow and stackexchange it should be organic, I hope. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, we have support email for feature requests and defect reports. So there will plenty of places to go for the appropriate issue.

Answer (score 4):

I added the tag, by adding it to the three questions that are actually *about* TickZoom.

I also added a (minimal) tag wiki. See [tickzoom](/questions/tagged/tickzoom).

Comment: Thanks. And +1 for the idea of adding a tag wiki. That was new for me.

Comment: None of those questions actually has any relevance to the tickzoom product - that's bad tagging :(

Comment: @Iain: Then there are no questions to tag with tickzoom. Feel free to remove them again, and my apologies if I misjudged the relevance of the TickZOOM component in those questions.

Comment: @lain You're right, of course. I'm learning. I've studied all the links and understand better when tags get added. We will wait till some actual tickzoom questions get posted. Thanks!