# Site for asking questions about Requestly (or in general some specific web browser tool)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

Requestly is a [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) and Firefox extension for [modifying network requests](https://www.requestly.in/home/) with ~50K users on Chrome and ~10K on Firefox. Can some Stack Exchange site be used by Requestly users to ask their questions and Requestly team can answer those questions there?

Questions asked by Requestly users are more general and can be helpful to other users and this is why we are looking for some open platform like `Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange` instead of replying on email.

### Nature of questions look like:

1. How to setup a redirect rule to redirect Google search result to specific URL?
2. How to use Wildcard matches operator for some use case
3. Need help in setting up headers rule

And so on..

Needless to say, sometimes users have questions very specific to their domain which may not be helpful to other users but even then the response will be helpful in understanding the tool.

I want to know the answer in general sense because the question applies to any tool for which users need a forum like platform for asking questions/support.

Possible options I could see is:

1. There exists some Stack Exchange site for asking questions specific to a web tool which can be utilized.
2. We can setup a new site under Area 51 and continue using it. We are happy being in under Area 51 as long as services are not stopped due to low activity.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser extensions and, well browsers would probably fit under [Super User](https://superuser.com). It's worth looking at [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) if it's a *purely* web tool, which this isn't.

Supporting software is also *explicitly* mentioned in the [help pages everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/product-support). It's also worth reading [the bits on how to not be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), just to know what the boundaries we expect are, and maybe get familiar with the existing sites that you might find these questions on to get a feel of their culture.

I *personally* think that setting up a well organised/written tag wiki (and a single question to 'seed' it) and using it alongside regular support channels would be the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: Thanks @Journeyman. How could I forget about SuperUser site. Super like your last line.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this looks like it could be suitable for Super User, if you structure it right.

Please be aware that Super User and other Stack Exchanges sites are [not suitable as a way to outsource your entire customer support channel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/781723).  It's only suitable for questions that fit our model.  It's not suitable for things like bug reports, feature requests, general discussion, questions that are specific to a single user, and so on.

In particular, please make sure to read [the guidance on using Stack Overview for technical support for your product](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/781723), as well as [this broader guidance for other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195558/160917).  Note that Stack Exchange sites will only be suitable for questions that fit our model.  We're not a forum, and we work a bit differently from other tech support forums that your users might be used to.  Users who are unaware of that might find their interactions frustrating.  So, to give your users the best chance at having a good experience, when you suggest asking on Super User, it would be helpful to provide a brief guidance on the Stack Exchange model, so that people only ask questions that fit our model.

In the past there have been companies that have not done a good job of respecting this distinction, and it has led to some friction.  (See, e.g., [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295869/781723), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296893/781723), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/781723), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303712/781723), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327707/781723), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342143/781723), [7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360409/781723).)  You can prevent that by being aware of the pitfalls and establishing expectations appropriately with your team and your users.