# Using Stack Overflow for StockTwits's developer community

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm one of the developers at [StockTwits](http://stocktwits.com). We recently revamped our API and would like to use Stack Overflow for developers to ask questions and discuss issues related to our API, similarly to what Foursquare does (see [foursquare](/questions/tagged/foursquare)).

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326196/how-can-i-authenticate-my-calls-to-the-stocktwits-api) was recently tagged with [stocktwits](/questions/tagged/stocktwits), but an editor [removed the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12326196/revisions).

I also just received an e-mail from your team regarding this, which mentioned the post [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project).

We have no desire to outsource our entire customer support channel to Stack Overflow (we already have customer support in place for reporting bugs, feature requests, etc), but we would love to use SO for technical support and for developers to discuss common problems related to our API.

Could we do this? And could we make sure that the [stocktwits](/questions/tagged/stocktwits) tag is not removed from questions asked at Stack Overflow from now on?

I'm also following up via e-mail to your community team about this.

Comment: Is somebody going to answer that question, or is this going to be another one of those Facebook deals?  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard No, the author isn't talking about anything like the Facebook deal. This sounds more like the organic support Stack Overflow provides to *any* group of developers like what Jon Skeet is talking about here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974/98786.

Comment: It still seems weird that he has not answered the question he specifically linked too. If I was him, I would have done that before posting this question. It just looks better, giving more confidence that they will actually answer those questions rather than leave them laying around unanswered.

Comment: We got it resolved with their community team over email, but I added my answer below. Yes, we're looking for organic support and will be encouraging our developers to post questions using the 'stocktwits' tag from here on.

Comment: @SayemIslam, shouldn't it be your customers posting the questions, not your developers?

Comment: @Benjol If those customers happen to be building something w/ our API, then yes. But this is *not* a business/product matter, but a technical one related to our new API roll-out, and StackOverflow is a great avenue for developers to discuss engineering issues.

Comment: @SayemIslam, ok. I believe that one thing that *would* be frowned on is your support team 'seeding' Stack Overflow with common user questions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, we reached out to the community team and got this resolved via email.

For future reference though in case anyone else wants clarity on this, StackOverflow encourages developer discussions around tags related to technical matters, so long as you're not using it as a support/customer service channel related to your own product/company. That would obviously harm the quality of the community and would promote spam.