# Using Stack Overflow to discuss problems faced in a new software product

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I have been working on some open source tools on github and there are quite a few number of people using it at the moment.

The problem is that everytime they want to ask something or don't understand something, they end up creating an `issue` on github.

I wanted to create a tag on Stack Overflow for this purpose, but I don't have enough privileges at the moment to create a new tag. What should be the right procedure to use Stack Overflow for a new software product?

**Update:**
Tag name : wintersmith

Website: http://wintersmith.io

Question which needs `wintersmith` tag: [Out of the box support for deployment in wintersmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762081/out-of-the-box-support-for-deployment-in-wintersmith)

Comment: If you want a new tag, what is the specific name of the tag you want created, and what question(s) do you think it should be tagged to?  As for the questions themselves, whether they're about some new product on github shouldn't really be relevant.  It'd be just the same as asking a question about any other programming project ever.

Comment: Tags don't get created in the absence of questions. If there are questions related to a specific product or library, then a tag can be created for them. And keep in mind that SO is not a product support forum. Questions need to follow the site's guidelines.

Comment: See also: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project) - Stack Overflow cannot replace a bug tracker or discussion forum. Your title "discuss problems" doesn't look like a good start to me, SO's not for discussing stuff.

Comment: I've added the tag to the question for now. Read the linked questions thoroughly, you're walking a thin line between a legitimate tag and an abused issue tracker. Make sure to suggest a proper tag-wiki for your tag.