# Which Stack Overflow website on survey tools?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We're about to launch a new survey tool. For customer support and knowledge sharing we are looking for a great place on the web for receiving and answering questions on surveying in general and of course for questions regarding our survey platform.

Having used Stack Overflow for a long time now, we've grown to understand and appreciate the power of the Stack Exchange Q&A platform. Open, accesable, reputation management, etc.

Is there a niche site in the Stack Exchange network that would be suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: This is a bit unclear, can you clarify what kinds of questions would be asked in relation to your product? Also make sure to check out [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966)

Comment: You may want to also consider [Get Satisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/).

Comment: it is a web application yes. The type of questions will be regarding "how to accomplish this and that ..", can i export to spss? Is this questiontype supported / will be?

Comment: GetSatisfaction .... yeah ... 1200 us$/month. We're a startup. This is  something we cant afford. Plus ... i really like te reputation and openes of stackoverflow! I hope it fits here somewhere ...

Comment: @Pëkka thanks for the link. I get the picture. I'm not seeking for a promotion channel. Just a genuine Q&A location ... The knowledgebase that results from it, will be much better situated here than in a private forum thing....

Comment: If it's about using a web app, it's not going to be on topic on Stack Overflow. You may be interested in [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267)

Comment: @Pëkka There's a Stack Exchange for [users](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/3920/pekka) of web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For customer support and knowledge sharing we are looking for a great place on the web

It's an understandable desire to use an existing community, but the Stack Exchange network is unlikely to be a good fit for this.

Generally, questions are expected to come up organically, from within the community, following each community's individual guidelines.  See Jeff Atwood's answer in [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/138112)

Seeding a SE site with questions about your product (which doesn't have an organic community yet) doesn't really resonate with that. 
It probably wouldn't work well anyway. If you tell your users to come to a SE site for support, they're going to ask questions there that may be on topic for *your product*, but not the SE site. That would lead to closed questions and downvotes, and hence lots of pain for your customers.

While genuine questions about your product may well eventually show up in the right venue - say, [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) as Chris W. Rea suggests, or [Stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com) - it is not a good idea to view a SE site as the primary support resource for your product.

If you like the Stack Overflow user interface, you may want to peruse one of the [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267) to create a support resource with a  similar experience.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in a comment: *"it is a web application yes. The type of questions will be regarding "how to accomplish this and that ..", can i export to spss? Is this questiontype supported / will be?"*

Given that it's a web app, I'm surprised nobody yet mentioned **[Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**:

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Web Applications Stack Exchange** is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**
> - Features of browsers which are **directly** related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Bear in mind that Stack Exchange isn't meant to replace your customer support function. However, as a place for more general "how to" questions that can be helpful to many users, Web Apps might be suitable.  You could ask at their [meta](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) to confirm.

Comment: Seeding Webapps.SE with questions about an app that has no organic community yet (`We're about to launch...`) - especially in the hopes of replacing a regular customer support channel! - sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: @Pëkka Huh? Who said anything about seeding? I brought Web Apps to the OP's attention as the most likely *candidate*, and I suggested he *check with **their** meta.* I'm not saying what he proposes is a good or bad, just that **if** there is a place in the SE network, it might be Web Apps, and *that's* where he should follow up. Whether Web Apps is suitable or not should be a discussion taking place at Web Apps. Stack Exchange is a network of [*individual* communities](http://stackexchange.com/about), and, broadly speaking, we don't speak *for* them here, but we can speak *about* them here.

Comment: Those are fair points. But looking at the user's question - `For customer support and knowledge sharing we are looking for a great place on the web` I really think the only answer is "this isn't going to work anywhere around here." But I'll simply add an answer to that effect :)

Comment: @Pëkka Then you would be presuming to speak on behalf of the individual community in question, and in the wrong place. Let the discussion take place at Web Apps, and voice your concerns there.

Comment: No need, in this case, IMO. One of the Founding Fathers has [spoken on the subject,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/138112) and I'd be *very* surprised if a single SE site would be allowed to deviate from that fundamental principle.

Comment: Umm, [yeah, ***this.***](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/).  I still say take it to Web Apps meta.  Jeff Atwood doesn't work here any more, and Web Apps is a self-governing community, a system the "founding fathers" put in place, so until somebody at Stack Exchange decides to exercise a veto of some sort, I think it's up to the Web Apps community.

Comment: Sure, they can take it to Web Apps. I don't think it's going to change the outcome - using a SE site as a support resource and telling your customers to go there and ask questions about your product is a terrible idea, and it isn't going to work. (The Facebook thing was negotiated with Jeff and Joel, and custom built by the team - it's hardly a valid comparison to this case. It has also since been scrapped.)

Comment: @Pëkka (True, yes, the "sub-site" custom bits were scrapped, but the link works, the tag persists, and the wealth of Q&A remain and grow each day. Facebook aside, there are many web apps whose APIs are asked about on Stack Overflow, and whose user functionality is apropos at Web Apps.)  TTYL.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) might be [a good place to start](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=survey).

Perhaps [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for the processing of your data, but you'll have to take a look at the help center to see if you're ontopic there.

Comment: he jeroen, thanx for the pointer.I got the impression it is intended for students only. Our userbase (hopefully) will contain students and small businesses....For students only it would be perfect match.  Maybe the superuser or webapplications??  Or maybe on different sites?? Stats indeed is on topic as well...argggg....

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it is you want to do but as far as I can tell, Academia is open to everyone in the research field, not just students. Perhaps you can share an example question/topic that you would talk about?