# Tag without Question

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I am developing new framework that will be released soon.

I want to use Stackoverflow as my support site. If anyone got question he should ask it here. Also I want to suggest people to use some unique tag so it will be easier for me to fallow.

Can I create new tag, without asking question for future use?

Comment: Before you do this, make sure to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217351/using-stackoverflow-for-community-product-and-paying and its answers (newer than the duplicate)

Comment: No, not a dupe, this is about tag creation.  The linked posts give good information for the user, but aren't the answer to his question.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a duplicate, but the linked questions are extremely important.  Do not throw your users into Stack Overflow as a general support site.  You need to maintain your own support channels (even if it is just email) for bug reports, feature requests, complaints, etc.  Questions on how to use the framework **can** be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but won't always be.

Answer (score 0):

No, there needs to be a question that the tag should be applied to before it can be created, or a wiki created for it.

Comment: Can you explain more about the wiki option please

Comment: @Babibu Tags, once created, can have a wiki to explain how they should be used.

Comment: @Babibu here's the C# wiki, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to create a question to create a tag.

What you could do is create a basic question, then self-answer it, so that you can get the tag created.
(When the framework is released, not before)