# Encouraging software publishers to use StackExchange as support mechanism

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Whenever I deal with an application publisher's custom support mechanism because I can't see any evidence of activity on StackExchange, I always wish they'd just migrate to StackExchange, particularly when I get a prompt response from them. What a waste, I think, that my question and answer weren't captured on SE.

In cases where there is *some* activity for the application on SE, I'll post my question there and, if I get no response, reference the SE question in my email follow-up. In the case of [How to access secondary travis logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538733/how-to-access-secondary-travis-logs), that had a happy ending where the support person posted the answer to the SE site at the same time they emailed me.

My related meta questions are:

- Are there any obvious downsides to publishers effectively "giving up" their custom support mechanisms, or at least their custom forum, in favor of the appropriate SE site?
- Are there any obvious downsides to SE for publishers making this transition?
- Is SE staff engaged in any systematic marketing efforts to get publishers to make this transition?
- Is there any SE documentation which lists the advantages of publishers making this transition?

Comment: The thing that comes to mind is proprietary rules, confidentiality, etc . Big companies like tend to keep things in-house. Oracle has something called meta-link

Comment: related: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there any obvious downsides to publishers effectively "giving up" their custom support mechanisms, or at least their custom forum, in favor of the appropriate SE site?

SE is very demanding of those asking questions.  Customer support, as a rule, ought to demand as little as possible of the customers.  Telling your customer that their support request is a very low quality question, having it closed, and telling them, "You need to fix this question so that it meets the site's quality standards to have it reopened." when they don't know where the power button is on their WhatchaMaCallIt is a good way for a company to lose business.  (Both the creators of WhatchaMaCallIts and SE.)

Another issue, [as brought up in comments by Adel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220305/encouraging-software-publishers-to-use-stackexchange-as-support-mechanism/220308#comment714162_220305), is confidentiality.  Users submitting support requests may need to be providing confidential information, and supporters responding to requests may need to be providing confidential information.

> Are there any obvious downsides to SE for publishers making this transition?

It tends to result in a lot of low quality and repetitious questions, a lot of offtopic questions, and a very small number of high quality questions. (Facebook directing their support questions surrounding their programming SDK resulted in a ton of questions about regular users trying to use the front end browser UI on Stack Overflow, as one example.)

> Is SE staff engaged in any systematic marketing efforts to get publishers to make this transition?

When a site does decide to redirect users to SE for some/all of their support related questions SE does make an effort to assist those companies in how they go about redirecting the users so that the wording makes it clear what types of questions are allowed on the given SE site, that the sites aren't technically affiliated, etc.  This does help, but it can only go so far.

I am not aware of any significant efforts by SE to encourage companies to offload their support to SE.  If anything I've seen cases where SE has found companies doing this to have cause lots of problems for everyone (see the first question) and has worked to try to *limit* how this is done.

> Is there any SE documentation which lists the advantages of publishers making this transition?

Not to my knowledge, which is not to say that this doesn't exist somewhere.

Comment: +1 and thanks. My "accept" is pending time restriction being lifted. This message will be deleted after I think you've probably read it (and would have been made "temporary" if that mechanism was available). :-)