# Where can I discuss support for an online software product using a Super User-like site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've posted an unresolved question that has lots of interest and can no longer be commented on, see link. It was put on hold as too broad. Could someone explain why Super User isn't allowing this information request? There is a specific tag for 'Google-Photos'.

The question that was originally posted on SU and migrated to Web Applications:
*[How to organize Google Photos?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311812/how-to-organize-google-photos)*

Generally, it seems okay to discuss support for a product on Super User if the community supports it according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282) by Jeff Atwood.

Is it because it is online software? I'm using it as I would desktop software like Microsoft Word. Where else can I ask about this? Why is Super User not for web services?

Comment: The existence of a tag does not necessarily make something on-topic. Usually the tag description will point out that it is off-topic and should be asked on so and so site. In this specific case there is no tag description for google-photos and there really should be. You'll also notice there are only 16 questions total for that tag so some slipped through the cracks but it is still far less questions than you'd expect if it was on-topic. So anyway, just fyi.

Comment: And, yes, questions about websites and web services are off-topic on superuser. Anytime you have a question about whether something is off-topic at a particular site, just navigate to that site's help center and you'll find a link for [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (<--for example, here is superuser's).

Comment: The tag has been updated.

Comment: That answer by Jeff Atwood precedes the existence of [webapps.se] by more than a year.

Answer (score 4):

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is a Stack Exchange site for users of web applications such as [Google Photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-photos).

Comment: Thanks SFTP and n8te. It would be helpful if this info was part of the 'on hold' notification, or it could have been just moved over. Actually, it would also be good to have a link to 'Web Applications' on the Help doc directly, I'm sure this happens a lot.  So should I ask that it get moved, or copy and paste it over? Thanks!

Comment: @alchemy It already is.  [**If your question is not specifically on-topic for Super User, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. For suggestions where to post your question instead, please see here.**](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)you failed to read the help center guidance.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out. I assumed because you didn't tell me where it should go, it didn't exist. The term 'off-topic' commonly implies that. It's probably too entrenched to change, but what you really mean is 'misplaced'. Also, why not link SE, Arqade, WebApps, etc. right on the Help page embedded in the 6 lines of common misplacements. I'm surprised it isn't as this would save the mods a lot of grief. It would also save the users a lot of time if the mods directed them where to post with a couple main variations of the off-topic form message that says it is a 'specific reason'.

Comment: I've migrated your question to webapps.

Comment: Alchemy - have you looked at how many SE sites there are?