# Own Company Tag On Some Stack Exchange Site

Tags: discussion, tags

At my current company we plan to start selling a complex physical product with a catchy name, so there is a necessity to create some forum where future users of our product will discuss it. Supposedly mostly technical stuff.

At first we decided to self-host some Stack Exchange clone site. But at the second thought, isn't it better to just create and promote **our own tag** (which will be a unique brand name of our product)?

This way we can promote the tag through our channels and users will head to one of existing Stack Exchange sites to discuss it. Some SE site will get more visitors and we will get a community, so this seems like a win-win.

So, here is the question: do Stack Exchange policies allow such tags?

Comment: See [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966/21960) and [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/21960)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends ...

If questions about your product are already on-topic on a Stack Exchange site, you can create the tag as soon as there are questions about the product. On Stack Overflow, it's relatively easy to [sponsor your tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/295232) and get your icon on it.

We also have a precedent now where a company is sponsoring [an entire site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) (though most of the questions aren't about the company itself). If you need a dedicated Stack Exchange for your product, a new proposal [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go but make sure to build a community around your product first, otherwise it's likely to be closed.

> some forum where future users of our product will discuss it

I'm not sure whether that would fit in the Q&A model of Stack Exchange. Questions like 'what would you like to be added to Product X' are bound to be closed as 'too broad' / 'primarily opinion based'.