# How can we get questions regarding our server through Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

We are an academic lab that developed several online servers.

Is there a way we can have people ask questions about the servers, and answer them directly on a Stack Exchange site (*[Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, for example)?

We would use tags, but none of us have enough reputation to start one.

Comment: maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project

Comment: Do you know who your users are and are there less then 50 users?

Comment: we've had hundreds of users, and get several questions a week.

Comment: the idea is to have users ask questions on stack exchange, where we, and other users can see/answer them.

Comment: If there is no-one able to create the specific tag at the specific site (people with questions, or you as team looking to answer them) you could always visit the site specific meta, and make a post there to request people to instate the tag for you. Likewise you could find a moderator in chat and ask for their help.

Comment: @Luuklag that assumes they have enough rep to do either of those

Comment: @EkadhSingh well that is the best way to do it, and requires less rep then creating a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

Note: only do the following as long as it follows Jeff’s guidelines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/560258). Also, check out the links given to you in the comments section.

### Here are some steps that you should take if you want to do that

1. Check if it would be on topic for a [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). If you are unsure if it would be on-topic somewhere, get 5 reputation on that site and ask on its per-site meta whether questions of a certain type would be on-topic there. Getting 5 reputation is fairly easy, getting a single upvote on a question or answer, or getting 2 suggested edits approved.
2. Assuming it is on topic for a Stack Exchange site (if not skip to step 5), see if there is an existing tag that would cover what you want to talk about.
3. If there’s an existing tag and an existing site where what you want to talk about is on topic, great! All that’s left is to double check on the per-site meta (which is optional) and then ask away.
4. If it’s on topic for one site, but there is no tag, here’s something you can do. Get enough rep to participate in meta (step one explains how to do this easily), then make a post saying “I think question about whateverYourTopicIs would be on topic here, but there is no tag. Could somebody please create a tag for these types of questions?” Or something similar to that. Make sure you explain why you think that those types of questions are on topic. Note that tags need to have a question related to them to be created, so maybe you can post your question and tag it with a similar tag, then have somebody immediately edit the tag (plan that out beforehand) so that it appears to most users like it had the correct tag all along.
5. If there is no Stack Exchange site for that topic, check whether your topic is a good fit for Stack Exchange. If you’re not sure, check [over here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/). If it is a good fit for the Stack Exchange model, and people have legitimate interest in it, go to Area 51 and create a proposal. This requires 50 rep, but that can be easily gained by associating your email address.